# How to load the multiple data to x by x array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matlab-figure

I have a bunch of .txt text files. this file is included like this

e.g.

```
text1.txt-
1
44
22
100
..
..

text2.txt-
7
14
82
50
..
..


....


text260.txt-
31
4
62
700
..
..
```

like this, text#.txt have almost 260 files.

I want to load into MATLAB with array like this.

```
a = 
1   7  ... 31 
44  14 ... 4
22  82 ... 62
100 50 ... 700
..  .. ... ..
..  .. ... ..
```

As I know, the load() function is in MATLAB. But I don't know how to load into array format.

How to load the multiple data to x by x array in MATLAB ?

Comment: Does every text file contain the same amount of data (i.e. the same number of values)?

Comment: @rayryeng yes Right the same  number of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to slowly build up the array. My first thought would be to do this:

```
arr = [];
for i = 1:260
    arr = [arr; load(['text' num2str(i) '.txt'])'];
end
```

You start off with an empty array, and then iterate through the files, appending each file to the array. NB, if the final array is quite large you might want to consider a different approach involving pre-allocating the array:

```
arr = zeros(length(load('text1.txt')), 260);
for i = 1:260
    arr(:,i) = load(['text' num2str(i) '.txt'])';
end
```

Comment: Even if the number of files is not so large, preallocating the final array is still a good thing to do (for example it will show you if there is an `out of memory` error right from the start ... instead of bombing out on file 259/260 and trashing all the work done).